# How to make whole activity scrollable according to the data inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout, vertical-scrolling

I have tried LinearLayout inside which I put several textview. I completely use weights for each and every view. Problem arises when data becomes too much in lenght and textview not shows it completely. I also tried tabletlayout but that thing also not works beacuse ultimately tablelayout is inside linear layout having weight,so it doesn't grows beyond a certain limit. I want to know how can I make a activity scrollable with showing all data while using weights.

Answer (score 12):

Use Scrollview in xml Layout of your activity.

**Example**:
    XML code for your activity:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="KNOW MORE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I was talking about using weights completely and not using dp etc,when i use weights my textview has limited area to show.How can I do such scrolling while using weights.I want to show full page scrolled data

Answer (score 5):

You can Use Scroll View With Linear Layout as well as With Relative layout.

You Can try this code, Just Copy and paste in XML File.
U'll Get Your ans :)

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/black"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV_Welcome"
    android:text="ADD YOUR VEHICLE"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:textColor="@color/menu_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TV_Welcome"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_BlockNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Block No:"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"

        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner_BlockNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV_BlockNo"
        android:background="#558cff"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TV_FlatNo"
        android:text="Flat NO:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"

        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner_FlatNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV_FlatNo"
        android:background="#558cff"
        android:layout_width="300dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_VehicleNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vehicle No:"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_VehicleNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Vehicle No"
        android:textColorHint="@color/menu_glow"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV_VehicleNo"
        android:textColor="#558cff"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TV_VehicleType"
        android:text="Vehicle Type:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"

        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner_VehicleType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV_VehicleType"
        android:background="#558cff"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_OwnerName"
        android:text="Owner Name:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_OwnerName"
        android:hint="Enter Owner Name"
        android:textColorHint="@color/menu_glow"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_OwnerName"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="400dp">
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout06"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_MobileNo"
        android:text="Mobile No:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_MobileNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:hint="Enter 10 digit"
        android:textColorHint="@color/menu_glow"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_MobileNo"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="200dp"

        >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout07"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_TelNo"
        android:text="Telephone No:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_TelNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Telephone No"
        android:textColorHint="@color/menu_glow"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_TelNo"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout08"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_Example"
        android:text="(Example:0141-2206923)"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/version_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView_Submit"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/submit"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout08"
    android:onClick="doSubmit"></ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I was talking about using weights completely and not using dp etc,when i use weights my textview has limited area to show.How can I do such scrolling while using weights.I want to show full page scrolled data

Comment: What height and width you set in Your layout .because with layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a MapView and a table which should show some additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the map to 3 and the layout_weight of the table to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to  0px.

Comment: Hope It will help you , if not thn gv me your only xml code i will correct that one.... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your activity scrollable using ScrollView.
Its very simple and effective to use.Just copy code of ScrollView from below and paste it in your layout xml file. 
You can use this ScrollView with Linear as well as Relative Layout also.
Just need to remember one thing,ScrollView can have only one child widget.If you want more Children then wrap them into one container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/xyz.png"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView3"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView4"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_demo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I was talking about using weights completely and not using dp etc,when i use weights my textview has limited area to show.How can I do such scrolling while using weights.I want to show full page scrolled data

Comment: @PrashantSinghVerma show your xml so that i can help you with that.